Extracting zero-curve from swaps in quantlib
My result I'm new to the QuantLib library in Python and am trying to calculate the zero curve using IRS (interest rate swap) market quotes. My IRS curve is downward sloping, so I expect the zero curve to be above the IRS curve. However, I'm getting other result. Additionally, I don't understand how to set specific conventions for my IRS: the floating leg has quarterly payments of a daily average (reference rate is arbitrary and now 18%), while the fixed leg has annual payments.
Could you please help me with the following:

How to set the specific conventions for my IRS.
Why the zero curve is below the IRS curve when it should be above.
Thank you!

I wrote this code:
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

name = 'Own rate'
fixingDays = 90
currency = ql.USDCurrency()
calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE)  # Corrected initialization
dayCounter = ql.Actual360()
own_index = ql.OvernightIndex(name, fixingDays, currency, calendar, dayCounter)

# Step 3: Define the Function
def bootstrap_yield_curve(swaps, settlement_date, calendar):
    # Set evaluation date
    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = settlement_date

    # Create swap rate helpers
    swap_helpers = [
        ql.SwapRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate)),
                          ql.Period(*tenor), calendar,
                          ql.Annual, ql.Unadjusted,
                          ql.Actual360(), own_index)
        for tenor, rate in swaps.items()
    ]

    # Create Piecewise Yield Curve
    yield_curve = ql.PiecewiseFlatForward(settlement_date, swap_helpers, ql.Actual360())

    return yield_curve

# Example Usage
settlement_date = ql.Date(30, 8, 2024)

# MY IRS market rates
swaps = {
    (3, ql.Months): 0.1898,
    (6, ql.Months): 0.1978,
    (9, ql.Months): 0.2010,
    (1, ql.Years): 0.2004,
    (2, ql.Years): 0.1930,
    (3, ql.Years): 0.1840,
    (4, ql.Years): 0.1755,
    (5, ql.Years): 0.1685,
    (6, ql.Years): 0.1630,
    (7, ql.Years): 0.1584,
    (8, ql.Years): 0.1538,
    (9, ql.Years): 0.1500,
    (10, ql.Years): 0.1471
}

# Bootstrap the yield curve
yield_curve = bootstrap_yield_curve(swaps, settlement_date, calendar)

# Prepare data for DataFrame
data = []
for tenor in swaps.keys():
    maturity_date = settlement_date + ql.Period(tenor[0], tenor[1])
    zero_rate = yield_curve.zeroRate(maturity_date, ql.Actual360(), ql.Continuous).rate()
    swap_rate = swaps[tenor]

    # Format the maturity amount as a string
    maturity_amount = f"{tenor[0]} {'Months' if tenor[1] == ql.Months else 'Years'}"

    data.append((maturity_amount, swap_rate, zero_rate))

# Create DataFrame
df_yield_curve = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Maturity (Amount)', 'Swap Rate', 'Zero Rate'])

# Display the DataFrame
print(df_yield_curve)
df_yield_curve.plot()
plt.show()

As a result I get:
  Maturity (Amount)  Swap Rate  Zero Rate
0           3 Months     0.1898   0.185435
1           6 Months     0.1978   0.185435
2           9 Months     0.2010   0.186600
3            1 Years     0.2004   0.186806
4            2 Years     0.1930   0.178363
5            3 Years     0.1840   0.171031
6            4 Years     0.1755   0.162900
7            5 Years     0.1685   0.155312
8            6 Years     0.1630   0.148903
9            7 Years     0.1584   0.143436
10           8 Years     0.1538   0.138011
11           9 Years     0.1500   0.133119
12          10 Years     0.1471   0.129236

But I'm sure that values in third column should be higher than values at the second column (for 1-3Y at least)
